# swift open urls from pdf file

Tags: swift, pdf

I'm working with pdf files that have urls inside it, and it's presented like images, I want the pdf to be presented like html file, so when the user clicks on a url inside the document it opens the url using safari

I'm using this library to read pdf files

https://github.com/Alua-Kinzhebayeva/iOS-PDF-Reader

and I have no problem to migrate to another library if it supports what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a quick look at that library, it appears it is rendering each page as an image and then displaying it. It would probably be pretty tough to use that library to allow clickable links.

I don't have any experience with 3rd party solutions but theres a couple ways to do it provided by Apple.

You could show the pdf in a `WKWebView` or a `QLPreviewController`. Both have delegate methods that are called when a link is clicked.

Comment: I used WKWebView it's working fine but I'll make a lot of work to customize it and add some options but it seems like the only option I got :"D 
Thanks dear